# Replace values from a known variable with PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable in PHP that contains a template of a card I use :

```
$template = '
    <div class="card">
        <h1>{{CARD_TITLE}}</h1>
        {{CARD_IMAGE}}
        {{CARD_LINK}}
    </div>
';
```

During a foreach, I would like to replace theses `{{CARD_VALUES}}` by these equivalents found in the array.

So I tried:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo strtr($template, array('{{CARD_TITLE}}' => $item['title']));
    echo strtr($template, array('{{CARD_IMAGE}}' => $item['image']));
    echo strtr($template, array('{{CARD_LINK}}' => $item['link']));
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas why please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're echoing the result each time you do a replacement, instead of doing all the replacements and then doing the echo. This should work:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo strtr($template, array('{{CARD_TITLE}}' => $item['title'],
                                '{{CARD_IMAGE}}' => $item['image'],
                                '{{CARD_LINK}}' => $item['link']));
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ftqqs)